# Changing of directories on linux scripts

Tags: linux

Can i get some help please, I need to change directories within a script so that different commands can act on the different directories within the script. I currently use Redhat
I have tried the following; 
where xxxx is my current directory ( where the script is location) and 
new_folder is one of the subfolders I need the script to work on
1.  cd “/data/xxxxx/new_folder” 
2.  cd ‘/data/xxxxx/new_folder’ 
3.  cd “./new_folder”

Your help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If using a full path is not an option, try using a path variable to accommodate that info.
e.g. 
`myFolder="/home/users/xxxxx"`
and then using the variable like this:
`cd $myFolder/;`